# What determines the view folder structure in ZF2?

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes, zend-framework2

What determines the view folder structure in ZF2?  I followed the initial ZF2 tutorial with the [Album app](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/user-guide/modules.html) and noticed the location of the views for the album module are in `/module/Album/view/album/album/*.phtml`.

What dictates the `/album/album/` portion?
Why are those directories all lowercase?
Why is it the same name nested?
In what situations would they not be the same?

I assume the answer lies within the `module.config.php` file.  But I've tried playing with combinations with the 3 instances of `album` by trying to change each to `album1` individually to see the effect it had.  Here is my `module.config.php` with the results of each change commented next to it.

```
return array(
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Album\Controller\Album' => 'Album\Controller\AlbumController',
        ),
    ),

    // The following section is new and should be added to your file
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'album' => array( //When switching to `album1` I get "Route with name "album" not found"
                              //If this is anything but `album` I get this error, regardless of the other 2 values.
                'type'    => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/album[/:action][/:id]',    //When switching to `album1` I get "The requested URL could not be matched by routing."
                                                                //If I change my url to /album1 though, it works so long as the first is still `album`
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Album\Controller\Album',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),

    'view_manager' => array(
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            'album' => __DIR__ . '/../view',    //Changing this seems to have no effect.
                                                //I even changed this to `abc123` and it still worked while the other two instances were still `album`.
        ),
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, ZF looks for views using `/<module>/<controller>/<action>.phtml`. 'module', 'controller' and 'action' are normalized to lower-case, with camel cased words converted to dashes.

In your example, the word 'album' is repeated because both the module and controller are called that. If you had a 'tracks' controller in the album module, and were viewing the 'add' action, by default ZF would look for the view in `/album/tracks/add.phtml`.

As to *why* the names are converted to lower-case, off the top of my head I can't remember. It may be because PHP class/function names are not case-sensitive, it may be because generally people use lower-case words in URLs, or it may just be because generally this is how people organise websites outside of frameworks. Probably some combination of these things.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much - again lol.  The camel case being converted to hyphens is what threw me off.  I had a module and controller named `ProductBriefs` and couldn't understand why it was looking for `product-briefs/product-briefs/action.phtml` when I had no instance of `product-briefs` in my code.